# ScrollTo animation on div with variable offset top not working correctly

Tags: javascript, jquery, animation, var, scrolltop

I'm struggling toscroll to the correct slide when clicking the right button navigation menu. When clicking the menu button it brings up a list of links. Clicking one of the links for the first time will scroll you to the correct slide. If you try clicking a different link it will break. If you refresh the page and click a link it will take you to the correct slide, if you click that same link again it will animate to the first slide, now if you click any other link it will slide to the correct slide.

I'm not sure why it is doing this, its almost as if it needs to go to the first slide again to find the correct slide. I pass a variable to the slide animation that gets set from the menu item and find the elements offset. When console.logging these variables it seems the variables arent being set correctly, but when removing the animate the variables seem to be set correctly. I am completely stumped as to why it is doing this. Please help. http://projects.fireworkx.com/pc/index.html

```
    var appWindowWidth;
    var appWindowHeight;
    var htmlbody = $('#slidesContainer');
    var htmlbodyScroll;
    var iconPreloader = $('.iconPreloader');
    var globalButton = $('#globalMenu');
    var globalMenu = globalButton.next();
    var globalLinks = globalMenu.find('li');
    var homeLinks = $('#homeSlideNavigation').find('li');
    var subLinks = $('.slideContainer').find('.sectionNavigation');
    var iconLinks = $('.slideContainer').find('.iconNavigation');
    var currentSlide = 1;

    var slideElement;
    var slideElementOffset = 0;


    var totalVerticalSlides = $('#slidesContainer').children('.mainSlide').length;
    var slideContainerWidth;
    var slideCount;
    var platformOSTimeout;
    var currentTouchMove;
    var lastTouchMove;
    var swipeDirection;

clickToSlide = function(dataslide,scrollDirection) {
    if(scrollDirection === 'vertical') {
        slideElement = $('.mainSlide[data-slide="' + dataslide + '"]');
        slideElementOffset = slideElement.offset().top;

        console.log('currentSlide ' + dataslide);
        console.log('slideElementOffset ' + slideElementOffset);

        slideElement.addClass('animate');

        htmlbody.animate({
            scrollTop: slideElementOffset,
            scrollLeft: 0
        }, 500, function() {
            htmlbody.clearQueue().finish();
        });
    }
},



globalSlideNavigation = function() {
        globalButton.on('click', function(e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            e.stopPropagation();
            globalMenu.toggleClass('active');
        });

        globalLinks.on('click', function(e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            dataslide = $(this).attr('data-slide');
            clickToSlide(dataslide, 'vertical');
        });

        htmlbody.on('click', function(e) {
            if(globalMenu.hasClass('active')) {
                globalMenu.removeClass('active');
            }
        });
    },
```

Comment: It seems if I change the var htmlbody = $('#slidesContainer'); to var htmlbody = $('html, body'); and change var totalVerticalSlides = $('#slidesContainer').children('.mainSlide').length; to var totalVerticalSlides = $('#body').children('.mainSlide').length; and in the index.html remove the <div id="#slidesContainer"> div wrapping the slides it works. But animate doesn't work with html and body on iPads. I need the scroll to work on a div element.

Comment: incidentally, I'd be careful with posting client work to stackoverflow, may be that it's all fine, but you never know, some clients can be overly protective and not want anyone to know that they're having work done for them. Best to do a quick mockup of your problem if you can in jsfiddle or the like and post that instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason it's jumping around like that is because .offset() gets the position of the element relative to the document [[https://api.jquery.com/offset/]](https://api.jquery.com/offset/%5d), so when you use scrollTop to set the position of page you're resetting .offset() of that element to 0, as it's now positioned at the top of the document. Same goes for if you use .position()

Because of this, when you click the nav again you're telling the page to set the scrollTop to 0, so it goes to the top of the page. If you click another element then it'll get it's position from 0, so work, or if you're further down the page it'll get it's offset based of the current position on relative to the scroll position, so it could be a negative or a number less than it's position from 0. Hope that makes some sense, not sure I've explained it very well.

To get the value of the element you want to go to you need to get the current scroll position and then add on the position to the section you want to view next and then use that as the scrollTop() value.

Here's a working demo for you: http://jsfiddle.net/andyface/LrG59/ you can see the values in the console for both just the offset position, which you're currently using and then the position based off the current scrollTop() value. Essentially, this is the only change you should have to make.

```
scrollPosition = htmlbody.scrollTop() + slideElementOffset = slideElement.offset().top;

htmlbody.scrollTop(scrollPosition);
```

Hope that helps

Comment: Thanks andyface, I will try it out and let you know how it goes.

Comment: Thanks so much andyface for helping me. It works! I would up vote you but I'm new to stack overflow and my rating is to low, but I really really appreciate your help. Keep well.

Comment: No probs, should still be able to mark my answer as correct, I think :)

Thanks :D